# Using variables in an object name

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie and this is my first post. I am having to use this sort of code a lot, so some guidance will be much appreciated. I am unsure how to best title/ask this question, but I want to simplify the code below in Excel VBA.

```
txtItem1.Value = txtItem2.Value
txtItem2.Value = txtItem3.Value
txtItem3.Value = txtItem4.Value
txtItem4.Value = txtItem5.Value
txtItem5.Value = txtItem6.Value
txtItem6.Value = txtItem7.Value
txtItem7.Value = txtItem8.Value
txtItem8.Value = txtItem9.Value
txtItem9.Value = txtItem10.Value
```

*Once I have a better understanding I can update the title to make it more useful for others.

Comment: *I want to simplify the code below* - how do you want to simplify it? A possible candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Text Boxes in Excel and your naming convention remains contiguous, you can do something like this:

```
For i = 1 To 9
    Me.Controls("txtItem" & i) = Me.Controls("txtItem" & i + 1).Value
Next
```